# Map a sequence of letters in insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I can already map a key combination in insert mode:

```
:inoremap abc <do stuff>
```

However, this has a few drawbacks:

- When typing a partial version of the sequence, such as `ab`, the characters aren't actually displayed for a short amount of time, since it's "waiting" to see whether you're going to type the full command. This is undesirable; I want to map a chain of letters without pausing if a partial substring of the chain is entered.
- If I type `ab`, then pause (and wait until the characters actually appear as mentioned in the above point), then type the `c`, the command is not executed. I want the command to be executed no matter how long I wait.

I would use an `iab`, but that doesn't work because:

1. It requires entering a space after the string
2. I can't execute arbitrary commands with it, only insert a string of text.

Is there any way to execute a command or keystrokes if a certain string is entered in insert mode, without using a map (which will annoyingly pause every time I type an `a` and not work if I wait too long)?

Comment: These drawbbacks are also true for `:cnoremap abc <do stuff>`...

Comment: There's no delay when you do `ab<any key>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```
let s:inputBuffer = ''

augroup _silentInsertTrigger
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertCharPre * call <sid>OnPreEnterChar()
    autocmd InsertLeave * call <sid>OnInsertLeave()
augroup END

function! s:OnPreEnterChar()
    let s:inputBuffer .= v:char

    if s:inputBuffer[-3:] ==# 'abc'
        echo '<do stuff>'
    endif

    return v:char
endfunction

function! s:OnInsertLeave()
    let s:inputBuffer = ''
endfunction
```