# Two character remap sometimes failing in INSERT mode

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, escape

For 4-5 years I've had the following in my `.vimrc` file:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

which I understand is pretty conventional, and I've never had problems until recently.

Every so often, typically when load is higher than usual, this remapping doesn't work and I end up with something like `jj;wq` in my document.

What would be the best way to go about increasing the reliability of this remapping? Is this uncommon, maybe indicating a system or keyboard problem?

I'm using vim version 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, with [this](https://github.com/jrumbut/MyVimRC/blob/master/.vimrc) .vimrc

Comment: Maybe you could play with the value of the 2 options `'timeout'` and `'timeoutlen'`. For example, if you type `:set notimeout` or if you increase the value of `'timeoutlen'` (let's say to 3s `:set timeoutlen=3000`). Does it change anything ?

Comment: @saginaw I'll try that and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry `set notimeout` was a complete bad idea, however slightly increasing the value of `'timeoutlen'` might still be worth a try. You could also look at the options `'ttimeout'` and `'ttimeoutlen'` but normally those only concern key codes not mappings so they shouldn't be useful here.

Comment: It does appear the `timeoutlen` has an impact, if you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it. There's also a more complicated method, that doesn't quite suit my needs but is nonetheless interesting, here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/563/map-a-sequence-of-letters-in-insert-mode?rq=1

Comment: Indeed you're right, it was very interesting to read, however I was unable to tweak the code so that it escapes from insert mode, sorry. Apart from an `:echo` command, the other Ex commands I tried resulted in an error `E523`. If my answer does not fully solve your issue, feel free to not accept it and to update your question to get more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options `'timeout'` and `'timeoutlen'` control how Vim will treat typed characters when they are part of a mapping. By default `'timeout'` is enabled and `'timeoutlen'`'s value is 1000 (ms).
It means that by default when you hit a character that is part of a mapping, Vim will wait 1s before deciding whether you are typing the `{lhs}` of your mapping or if it's just a single character.

When you hit the first `j` in your mapping, you could imagine that Vim has triggered a timer, and you have 1s to type the second `j` if you want to escape. After 1s, your first `j` is not considered as part of a mapping anymore, it's just a character. So in the end Vim will just insert `jj`.

Usually Vim receives your `j` almost immediately after you typed it. However, if your system is under a heavy load maybe it adds some lag between the moment where you hit `j` and the moment Vim receives it. When it happens it's as if you typed `jj` with more than one second between the 2 characters. If that's the case, then you could increase the value of the `'timeoutlen'` option so that your second `j` has enough time to reach Vim before the timeout occurs.

For example, to increase the length of the timeout to 2s, you could add in your vimrc:
`set timeoutlen=2000`

For more information, see:

```
:help timeout
:help timeoutlen
```