# How do I map a sequence of letters in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, replace

After trying to make this work:

[Map a sequence of letters in insert mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/563/map-a-sequence-of-letters-in-insert-mode/19975#19975)

I can’t get the correct answer to work. Is it still working? Can anyone post a working .vimrc file?

I want to get this:
When I type  `'a` in insert mode I want vim to change it to `á`.

Comment: Related: [What is the easiest way to insert Unicode characters into a document?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2254/51) and [What is the easiest way to insert en dash in Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2199/51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get á by typing 'a in insert mode is to first `:set keymap=accents`.

Comment: Wow, consider it done! That was fast and direct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might use digraph to enter á.

Just enter the sequence <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>.

Or: Set the option digraph with `:set digraph`. Then you can enter á with <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>.

Read more about digraphs with `:help digraph`.

If you need it regularly, the better solution seems `keymap` as proposed by @troydj.